# Problems having CMake access SWIG and link a java library to an existing C++ project

Tags: java, c++, cmake, swig

I am modifying a CMake file of an existing open source project written in C++ to try to link it to a SWIG Java interface file. The code I have pieced together from other forums and tinkering around is this :

```
    FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
    INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH})
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/avogadro/src)
    SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")
    SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(mainwindow.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
    SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(mainwindow.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")
    SWIG_ADD_MODULE(mainwindow java mainwindow.i mainwindow_wrap.c)
    SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(mainwindow ${JAVA_LIBRARIES})
```

Is there anything wrong with what I have written/found? When I run the cmake command, it builds. Yet when I run make -j3 (I need to do this to access the newly integrated libraries later on), it crashes, giving the very ambiguous error message "make: *** [all] Error 2 "

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with this code (if anything), but you can see what command causes the crash perhaps by using "make VERBOSE=1" to see what command executes just before the error/crash...

Comment: @DLRdave, yep. I noticed this " jni.h: No such file or directory" was at the end. So, hopefully, all I should need to do is set the JVM path. I'm new to CMake, so I am looking up code to do this in the best manner.

Comment: I fixed my particular problem by adding the full path to the wrapper and interface files in  the set source properties commands. To point it towards jni.h, I added " FIND_PACKAGE(JNI REQUIRED)" at the beginning.

Comment: Since you've found the "answer" ... you should answer your own question, and then accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my particular problem by adding the full path to the wrapper and interface files in the set source properties commands. To point it towards `jni.h`, I added `FIND_PACKAGE(JNI REQUIRED)` at the beginning.